# Getting Server Certificate/SSL in Servlet

Tags: tomcat, servlets, ssl, jetty, ssl-certificate

I have a web application (.war file) that can be deployed in Tomcat or Jetty or any other servlet container. I want to know the Servlet container's SSL certificate details (e.g. when the certificate will expire, who is the issuer etc.)

Is it possible to get the Server Certificate or SSL details from a Servlet?

Comment: Are you asking for this information during a request, or do you want to get it offline for programmatic purposes?

Comment: I want to get the information during servlet initialization phase (inside init()) so that I can use it in every request (inside service()) method.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just connect to yourself on the appropriate port with an SSLSocket, get the SSLSession, get the peer certificate. Don't send anything.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen The OP specifically stated 'in a Servlet'. I don't know what else that could possibly mean. And he has now confirmed it, *before* you posted this comment.

Answer (score 1):

Technically speaking there is no one SSL certificate for a container.  The server may have many connectors, each connector may have many certificates and SNI is used to select one only as a connection is made.

So for a portable servlet, you should not be not be getting the details during init as they may differ for every request.

Eitherway, you can't do this with standard APIs.  In a request you can downcast the request to a jetty request and then navigate through several getters to get the Ssl EndPoint and from there the SslEngine, which will tell you about the certificate used for that request.